# How do I retrieve the sha of git commit being generated in a commit-msg hook?

Tags: git, githooks, sha

Hoping there is a way to discover the sha for the commit being generated.  Im inside a commit-msg hook.  I'd like to append the sha to the end of the commit message so my git gui can build a link to GitHub for me.

Comment: What do you mean "your git gui"?

Comment: If "your git gui" has a reference to a commit, it already trivially has the hash for the commit, since the hash *is* the reference to the commit, so i don't see why you would want the hash in the commit message. It's like you want to cross the river to get water.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Unfortunately, source tree does not give the parsing tools access to the hash.  It only allows us to parse the commit message and build links from that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SHA1 hash generation depends on the commit message, so appending the hash to the commit message would cause the hash to be different. You've got a chicken or egg problem.

Answer (score 3):

The SHA1 has not yet been generated (the commit has not yet happened, because the hook can prevent it) and depends on the contents of the message.  So if your hook were to compute "what it would be" and then modify the message, the result would be different from the computed SHA1.

Thus, while it would be possible to compute "what the SHA1 will be", you can't then dump it into the commit message.

Here's how to compute the SHA1 of an actual commit, though, given the SHA1 of the commit :-) or a name that refers to it:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD > /tmp/t
$ git hash-object -t commit /tmp/t
ea5670c9d18fb1482ea2f3022c96e287afb3e906
$ git rev-parse HEAD
ea5670c9d18fb1482ea2f3022c96e287afb3e906
```

Thus, if you know the `tree`, all the `parent`s, the `author`, and the `committer` strings and have the message text, you can figure out what the SHA1 will be.